# Unable to load the file from filesystem using ResourceBundle

Tags: java

```
public static void loadFilters() throws MalformedURLException {
        File filtersFile = new File(CONFIG_DIR + "/" + FILTERS_FILE);
        URL[] urls = {filtersFile.toURI().toURL()};
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(FILTERS_BASE, Locale.getDefault(), loader);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getStringValue(bundle, ALLOW_TYPE_PATTERN_KEY))) {
            ALLOWED_TYPES = Pattern.compile(getStringValue(bundle, ALLOW_TYPE_PATTERN_KEY));
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getStringValue(bundle, DENY_TYPE_PATTERN_KEY))) {
            DENIED_TYPES = Pattern.compile(getStringValue(bundle, DENY_TYPE_PATTERN_KEY));
        }
        ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES = getListValue(bundle, ALLOW_MIME_PATTERN_KEY);
        DENIED_MIME_TYPES = getListValue(bundle, DENY_MIME_PATTERN_KEY);
    }
```

I am trying to load properties file using resource bundle kept outside the code in a separate directory. But when I try to do this way(above code) I am getting error as

```
ERROR [main] Can't find bundle for base name filters, locale en_US
```

And If I am keeping this file filters.properties in src/main/resources folder then this code is working fine... but when I keep it outside it doesn't works.. Don't know why..

And CONFIG_DIR contains \my\dir\conf and FILTERS_FILE contains filters.properties file.

FILTERS_FILE has value `filters.properties` and FILTERS_BASE has value `filters` and urls got the value as `[file:/C:/my/dir/conf/filters.properties]`

And filters.properties file is in /my/dir/conf/filters.properties

Comment: What are the values of `FILTERS_FILE` and `FILTERS_BASE`? Does the former point to a directory or a file? `URLClassLoader` assumes that a URL either points to a directory if it ends with `/`, otherwise it assumes that you're pointing at a jar file.

Comment: @G_H, I have updated the question.. And FILTERS_FILE has value filters.properties and FILTERS_BASE has value filters and urls got the value as [file:/C:/my/dir/conf/filters.properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having the file point to the directory rather than the actual properties file. So just change the first statement of that method to

```
File filtersFile = new File(CONFIG_DIR + "/");
```

If `FILTERS_BASE` contains `filters`, that should be enough. You don't need the full `filters.properties` name since the .properties prefix is appended by the `getBundle` method.